# Как автоматически чистить RAM с помощью python?

Tags: python, big-data

В наличии 96GB оперативной памяти. Работаю с большими данными.

Когда я запускаю инстансы на одном наборе данных, у меня используется примерно 60GB оперативки. 
Соответственно, когда я запускаю другой инстанс на том же наборе данных (т. е. мне нужно еще 60GB данных), у меня вылетает ошибка:

```
Unable to allocate 11.0 GiB for an array with shape (501, 2942242) and data type float64
```

Она свидетельствует о том, что оперативной памяти недостаточно для обработки такого объема данных.
Чтобы ошибки не возникало, мне нужно остановить все другие инстансы и тогда RAM становиться свободным.

Можно ли как-то с помощью python чистить оперативную память с помощью какой-то команды? Например, мне бы подошел вариант, когда при запуске инстанса я чищу RAM.
Возможно, есть еще какие-о дополнительные способы для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Как вариант - пытаться убить процесс. https://qna.habr.com/q/387415

Comment: вы чей RAM собираетесь чистить? своего процесса? или чужих? если чужих - то только путем завершения этих процессов

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос — «нужно остановить все другие инстансы». Добавить к этому в общем-то нечего

Comment: Самый реальный способ, ИМХО, - воспользоваться средствами операционной системы. Как размер у вашего swap файла? Вам нужен своп не менее 60+60-90 = 20GB. Но для верности я бы взял больше. Когда потребуется куча памяти ОС выпихнет память вашего первого процесса в своп и освободит память для второго. Если своп будет на SSD, то это будет даже не фатально медленно.